# Using font awesome in wordpress theme

Tags: php, css, wordpress, font-awesome

I have installed theme flat-responsive and it has font awesome css inside.
I also see  this in functions.php

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'flat_responsive_font-awesome', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/font-awesome.min.css', array( ), current_time( 'mysql' ), 'all' );
```

But I couldn't use it, example `<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-lg"></i> fa-lg`
showing nothing. I want to do a custom css using this font awe some icon, how can i do?

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the css of the i class

```
i {   font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.3.0');
  src: url('font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.3.0') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('font/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.3.0') format('woff2'),
  url('font/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.3.0') format('woff'),
  url('font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.3.0') format('truetype'),
  url('font/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.3.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
}
```

upload the font family to your theme and also the font awesome css for the class you use e.g. `<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-lg"></i> fa-lg`